# PowerApps DataVerse storing data that has relation to another table

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

The idea is to store data in a table that has a relationship column (look up). I have two tables: Tools and Tool Tests. It is a one-to-many relationship - a Tool can have many Tool Tests. So, in the Tool Tests table there is a column for Tool. Whenever I create a Tool Tests record, I want that record to be related to a Tool. To my understanding, a value in the Tool column of the Tool Tests table should be entered that exists as a primary key in the Tools table.

The following code is what I am using. varTestData is data the I get after an API call and then have to iterate it with `ForAll` to go through all records. But I get and error on the line `'Tool': varSerialNo,`. The error is:

> Incompatible type. The 'Tool' column in the data source you're updating expects a 'DataEntity' type and you're using a 'Text' type.

I understand that the types are not correct, but I am unable to find anything on `DataEntity`. Is my approach incorrect at all or am I missing something in how I am assigning the value in the Collect function?

```
ForAll(
varTestData,
Collect(
    'Tallman Equipment Tool Tests',
        {
        'Torque Tool Model No.': 'Torque Tool Model No.',
        'Torque Tool Serial No.': 'Torque Tool Serial No.',
        'Beam Model No.': 'Beam Model No.',
        'Impacts Per Minute': Value('Impacts per Minute'),
        'Tool': varSerialNo,
        'Measurement Units': 'Measurement Units',
        'Peak Torque': 'Peak Torque',
        'Sample No.': Value('Sample No.'),
        'Test Duration': 'Test Duration',
        'Test Date': DateValue(Date),
        Time: Time,
        Torque: Value(Torque)
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Dataverse/DataEntity-Type/td-p/151948

It’s something that’s going on for yours. relationships are for Model-Driven apps.
In canvas apps, it’s horrible and won’t work as expected.

Comment: I dont really understand why they wouldnt make it better to use on the canvas apps. I cant use model driven apps because I need custom connectors.

Comment: The problem with these relationships is that in a model-driven app, you always have the linkable record selected with the primary key. In canvas apps, this doesn’t have to be. For your relationship to work, your tool test(let’s name it table B), should know first that the tools table exist(table A). If you do a lookup for the guid in table A and give that to table B, the relationship is able to execute.

Comment: From your last comment are you saying that it is possible to achieve what I want? I kind of understand what you are saying, but don't really understand how I would achieve that practically.

Also, what is "guid"?

Comment: Nevermind. I just googled guid and found my answer.